# Performance issue with alpine musl library

Tags: glibc, alpine-linux, qt

In order to build a complex C++ software based on Qt framework, I have prepared an alpine toolchain (for x86_64). This toolchain chroot contains :

- the alpine base package 3.16
- a list of installed packages (directly from alpine repository).
- I have compiled Qt 5.15.7 source code, and installed it (qmake, mkspecs,..) inside my chroot.

Finally, I have built the complex software with my toolchain (qmake build system).
The problem is that when running the software I have a very high latency. As a result, many tests failed (unit/integration/system tests). It seems that this performance issue is caused by musl libc of alpine.
**Questions:**

- Is there a patch or any solution to increase the performance of musl libc ?
- Is it possible to switch to glibc ? If yes, does alpine have a precompiled apk packages based on glibc ?
  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: switching from musl to something else simply sounds like Alpine is more trouble than it's worth – simply do the same as you're doing with Alpine, but on debian, Arch, Fedora…

Comment: Also, why compile Qt 5.15.7 yourself? You end up with something very custom. Fedora, for example, comes with *exactly* that version, so you can just install it from package repositories. That takes away most of your setup complexity. Debian sid (currently) comes with 5.15.7 as well, debian bookwork with 5.15.6; so does Ubuntu kinetic. So, in other words, your choice of a ultra-light Linux distro to give a heavy-weight toolchain has already made your whole problem a magnitude harder than it needs be! To absolutely no benefit: A dev installation of Qt5 will definitely dominate image size.

Comment: if you're *working* on alpine (why?), [alpine has podman](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Podman) (you don't even need Docker, but if you prefer docker, use that instead), so your whole chroot setup can replaced with a simple `podman run -it fedora:37` into which you install `dnf install qt5-devel`; done!

Comment: (what I'm saying is that trying to build your complex software on a system that's not musl-based takes very few lines of effort; you should probably do that to verify the source of your performance issues is indeed musl.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller
Thank you for your quick reply. The reasons why we have choosen alpine :   
1- it's multi arch (I forget to precise that I have also prepared an **armhf**  toolchain based on alpine, same steps as in x86_64, but  Qt was cross-compiled )
2- apk packages are lighter and more stable than other distributions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The cross-compiler tools for armhf  are built using alpine aports.

Comment: @MarcusMüller By the way, software performance in arm device is worse than x86_64 (not a surprise I think :D)

Comment: apk packages are not lighter nor more stable, as far as I can tell :) And it honestly won't matter if we're talking about something encompassing the whole of Qt5!

Comment: re: armhf: perfectly well supported by debian, by the way. Honestly, if you're adding a glibc to your alpine, you'll be bending it to be a worse alternative to just using debian. So I'd go for that.